# Populating Writer document with spreadsheet (Calc) as data source

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

I have **one** page (in Writer) that contains **4** the same boxes (business cards) with label as field from spreadsheet. During print i get the same record from spreadsheet per page (on first page is record number 1 four times), but need that first page have the first 4 records (1-4), second page have next four records (5-8) and so on. How to do it ? I hope you know what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [mail merge](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Using_Mail_Merge) for that, i believe -i've linked to the howto from OOo's own documentation